# Similarity transformation of projection matrix

Tags: opengl, opencv, camera, computer-vision, transformation

I have a similarity transformation **S** from world coordinate system 1 to 2. I also have a set of 3D points **x_i** and projection matrices **P_j** (3x4 or 4x4) of cameras in either world coordinate system 1 or 2.

I now want to transform the cameras (projection matrices) in system 1 to system 2.

Transforming the 3D points works as expected, but how would I do it with the projection matrices?

My approach was the following:

```
S = [Ss*SR | St]
P = [R | t]
```

Invert the projection matrix:

```
PP = inv(P) = [R.T | -R.T*t] = [RR | tt]
```

Rotate the orientation of camera:

```
RR' = SR * RR
```

Scale, Rotate and translate position:

```
tt' = Ss*SR*tt + St
PP' = [RR' | tt']
```

Invert the transformed matrix to obtain the projection matrix again:

```
P' = inv(PP')
```

where P and P' are the projection matrices in system 1 and 2, respectively.

Comment: Please check your question. You say you have "projection matrices P_j .. in world coordinate systems 1 and 2."  Then you say "I now want to transform ... projection matrices from system 1 to 2."  If you have both, then transformation isn't necessary.

Comment: @Gene This was not clearly phrased. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: I would say this question belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: downvote explain yourself please.

Comment: This is a reasonable OpenGL programming question.  I upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

Projection matrix P1 projects 3D points to image plane and thus to
2D points in the source coordinate system:

```
x' = P1 * X1
```

3D points can be transformed to the destination system by applying
the similarity transformation S:

```
X2 = S * X1
```

To obtain the projection matrix P2 that transforms the 3D point in the
destination system to the 2D points, which do not change:

```
x' = P2 * X2 = P2 * S * X1 = P1 * S^-1 * S * X1 = P1 * I * X1
```

and thus:

```
P2' = P1 * S^-1
```

Finally, a normalization by the scaling factor is necessary:

```
P2 = s * P2'
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this math. How are you calculating (or reasoning) your normalizing scale factor?

Comment: First, scaling either sides of the equation with a scaling factor does not invalidate it as projective space is independent of the scaling (x' = w*(u, v, 1).T while x' is the same point for all w, "points are actually rays" in projective space). The projection matrix and points in projective space are therefore only unique up to a scaling factor. So, scaling the projection matrix does not change the projection from X to x'. Normalizing the projection matrix is ultimately only necessary in order to extract the correct position in euclidean space (R, t). Hope it helps?

Comment: It does, thank you. Lastly, the normalization of the projection matrix, in which way are you normalizing it? I found scaling by 1/infinity_norm worked rather well, but I had no justification for why I was using that. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: I'd rather say you have to normalize with 1 / norm(R2, 2) where R2 is from P2 = [R2 | t2], which is basically equivalent to the inherent scale of the rotation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.  *Similarity transform* is not conventional OpenGL terminology. The pipeline starts with object coordinates.  A model transform M takes these to world coordinates (there is only *one* world coordinate system).  A view transform V takes these to eye coordinates.  Sometimes the view matrix is called the camera matrix because V takes a hypothetical camera line of sight vector and eye point to the world negative z axis and origin respectively.  A projection transform P takes the eye coordinates to homogenous (4d) clip coordinates. In parallel projections, these are the same as normalized device coordinates.  For perspective, the division needs still to be performed, but this can't be represented as 4x4 matrix ops and isn't important for what you want.  So the whole pipe in 4d is

```
d = P V M x
```

where `d` is a clip/normalized device coordinate and `x` is an object coordinate.  You can change any or all of the pipe as a scene is rendered. But it's unusual to change P or V.

So your question doesn't make much sense. A camera matrix V is described with a point and vector in eye coordinates.  If you want to see where those lie in object space, just multiply by inv(M).  Perhaps (I am guessing) what you have is two object spaces and corresponding model matrices to take these to a common world:

```
d = P V M_1 x_1
d = P V M_2 x_2
```

Now if you have an eye point and vector in object system 1 and need to get them to system 2, do the obvious thing.  Solve for x_2 in terms of x_1:

```
x_2 = inv(M_2) M_1 x_1
```

To say a camera matrix is "in" any particular coordinate system doesn't have meaning.  The matrix is between coordinate systems.

Comment: I should have described my problem in more detail. I only added the OpenGL tag as I use it to visualize my data, which is the result from a structure from motion solution in computer vision. Cameras here are the actual positions of image acquisitions in 3D object space and can be extracted from the inverse of the projection matrix. So, I actually do want to apply a similarity transformation. I did not know that the OpenGL terminology might be confusing here. Nevertheless, thank you very much! I think I'll try my luck at math.stackexchange as suggested above (I did not know about it before)?